# Slide dropdown open

Tags: html, css

**EDIT:** I couldn't find any solution without JS so I implemented it with JavaScript (solution as answer).

I am trying to create a slide-open-dropdown without any JavaScript. I've googled a bit but could not find any solutions using either a fixed `height`, using a fixed `max-height` or well.. JavaScript.

**What I've done:**

My Elements are the same `height` as my container so I could just use 3 times the height but now I have another constant.

**Code:**

```css
.dropdown_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown_title {
  background-color: #505050;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

.dropdown_content {
  background-color: #646464;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1; 
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .3s;
}

.dropdown_content > * {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown_content > *:hover {
  background-color: #7D7D7D;
}

.dropdown_menu:hover .dropdown_content {
 height: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown_menu">
  <p class="dropdown_title">Dropdown</p>
  <div class="dropdown_content">
    <a href="">Option 1</a>
    <a href="">Option 2</a>
    <a href="">Option 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create this?

Comment: transitions is the keyword you are looking for

Comment: Let me check if I understand your question: You want to make this without a fixed height on hover? If it is you can set the height of `dropdown_content` on hover to auto, but in this way you can't use transition. If you want to use transition use max-height and set it to a big number.

Comment: Unfortunately if you are wanting css only, then you have to have a fixed height / max-height

Comment: My advice: Get off the “without any JavaScript” train. While it is often times possible to built something like this using HTML & CSS only, the _usability_ is quite often terrible. JavaScript allows you to properly toggle attributes that are important for screen reader users, etc.

Comment: to add to misorude's comment - it is sometimes better to use js rather than css too: https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Comment: @misorude don't get me wrong I actually love JavaScript. Sure it has its stupid moments... well lots but It can be really powerful. The problem here is that I'm trying to make a component for a coworker and so I tried it to be easily implemented.

Comment: @IanWelerson I want my container to scale up to full height but dynamically, without any fixed `max-height` nor `height`

Comment: @misorude would you know a solution with JS? I'm also stuck there because I can't modify the `:hover` attribute.

Comment: @Elias using transitions it's not possible. To use transition you need to specify a size for element grow up, if you don't set the size (`auto` is not a defined size) the transition is not applied, but the element is grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked out a solution **with** JavaScript and will provide it for future use :)

Here is my code:

```js
"use strict";

document.querySelectorAll('.aDropdown').forEach(dropdown => {
  let body = dropdown.children[1];
  let titleHeight = dropdown.children[0].clientHeight;

  dropdown.style.height = titleHeight + "px";

  // Mouse enter listener
  dropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    // Variables
    let bodyHeight = 0;
    let selectionAmount = body.children.length;

    // Get the height of all children
    for(let i = 0; i < selectionAmount; i++) 
      bodyHeight += body.children[i].clientHeight;
  
    // Set the container to a certain height
    dropdown.style.height = (titleHeight + bodyHeight) + "px";
  });
  // Mouse leave listener
  dropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    dropdown.style.height = titleHeight + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
}
/* ABOVE THIS IS JUST PAGE STYLING */

.aDropdown {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(165, 165, 165);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: height .3s;
}
.aDropdown > .title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.aDropdown > .body > * {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.aDropdown > .body > *:hover {
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="aDropdown">
    <p class="title">DropDown</p>
    <div class="body">
      <a href="">Item</a>
      <a href="">Item</a>
      <a href="">Item</a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-height` instead of `height`, and set the max height on hover to a very big one. Also note that the transition time is relative to the full maximum height so you'll have to set a longer transition time.

```css
.dropdown_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown_title {
  background-color: #505050;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

.dropdown_content {
  background-color: #646464;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1; 
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.dropdown_content > * {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown_content > *:hover {
  background-color: #7D7D7D;
}

.dropdown_menu:hover .dropdown_content {
 max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown_menu">
  <p class="dropdown_title">Dropdown</p>
  <div class="dropdown_content">
    <a href="">Option 1</a>
    <a href="">Option 2</a>
    <a href="">Option 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown_menu">
  <p class="dropdown_title">Dropdown</p>
  <div class="dropdown_content">
    <a href="">Option 1</a>
    <a href="">Option 2</a>
    <a href="">Option 3</a>
    <a href="">Option 4</a>
    <a href="">Option 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using a massive max-height causes a delay before the closing animation (if you wait long enough for the opening animation to finish)

Comment: I am totally aware of that but as @Pete said the speed of the closing will vary. So it could be way to fast with few elements and look okay with tonnes (efforts are still very much appriciated).